# How do you patent commonly known technology?

Tags: us8037700

How do you "patent" something that's already being done in industry?  We've been building these since the 70's.  Our limit is -75 F.  But, I don't know that these guys are going there from what I read.  The solutions are all commonly known in this industry.
US 8037700 B2

Answer (score -1):

Claims 4-8, 16, 17, and 20 were deemed allowable under the firs examiner rejection  for the provisional corresponding to US8037700 B2. The remaining claims were rejected over US 6606872 to Smith as well as being known in the art. Applicant showed the difference between their claims and Smith and what is known in the art and the claims allowed with no further prosecution. Interestingly,  US8037700 was originally filed as a PCT WO2007/087248 in 2007 and rejected under lack of inventiveness under US 6463747 and US 5291745. The inventors amended their claims before filing their US provisional- probably based on comments from the PCT examiner and the application issued. I suggest you read the image file wrapper in Public Pair to see the course of prosecution. Since this patent was filed before AIA first to file rules and you could prove you invented first, you might challenge the validity of the issued patent.

Comment: "provisionals" do not get rejections - they are not examined. The OP does not say they invented anything, only that they have been doing something similar since the 70's. If they did invent it in the 70's and have been doing it since then it is way too late to file on it.